# range of $\cos(\frac{-7n}{6}\pi)$ where n is positive integer

Tags: calculus

How can I find the range of this function ? is it surjective ?
$ f (n) =\cos(\frac{-7n}{6}\pi)$

From the domain of the function I know that there are infinite many "holes" but how can I be sure that some values from the range $(-1,1)$ are missing ?

My idea is to consider continuity but I didnt get too far , I hope someone can give me some help or a hint.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use that
$$
\cos\left(-\frac76n\pi\right)=\cos\left(n\pi+\frac{n}6\pi\right)=(-1)^n\cos\left(\frac{n}6\pi\right).
$$

Comment: So there are 12 elements in the range ?

Comment: I mean 7 different elements in the range.

Comment: Yes. You could just enumerate them along with their pre-images.

Comment: Can you explain why you put (-1)^n ? does the values alternate between negative and postive?

Comment: Because $\cos(n\pi+x)=(-1)^n\cos(x)$ and also $\sin(n\pi+x)=(-1)^n\sin(x)$. Fun fact: $\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\sin(x)=\sin(x+n\frac\pi2)$. -- And yes, the sign alternates, but take care that $\cos(x)$ is negative for $x>\frac\pi2$, so you get $1,-\frac{\sqrt3}2,\frac12,-0, -\frac12,\frac{\sqrt3}2,-1,...$ which is not exactly alternating.

Comment: Thank you very much sir very helpful identity.

Answer (score 1):

To see that the range has *some* numbers missing it is enough to know that your *domain* is countable, so the *range* is also countable -- and therefore cannot contain any interval.

More precisely, you can easily see that $f(n)=f(n+12)$ for all $n$, so the range contains *at most* $12$ different points.

Comment: Thanks this was a bit helpfull but how can I express the range ?

Comment: @KasmirKhaan: Since the range is finite, simply writing it down with braces and commas would be a possibility. In this particular case, it so happens that each element of the range can be written exactly with integers and square roots, but whether that is worth the trouble depends on what you need the range _for_.